# How to find via Python the icon associated with a Windows file?

Tags: python, windows, shell, filesystems, shortcut

I'm developing a Python script to do file management on Windows. Essentially, I want to be able to move files to another location, and create in their place a shortcut to a Python script which will do intermediate steps before opening the relocated file. I can currently move files, create functioning shortcuts, and set the shortcut icon image. The only thing I have left is to figure out how to detect the icon which is displayed for the file.

-Need to set the icon for a shortcut (which points to a '.py' script)

-This icon should match that of an arbitrary filetype, exe, etc, which I have the path to

-Hopefully done programmatically through Python. os.system() calls are acceptable. Extra credit is given for not requiring additional modules (though I already have win32com, winshell, pythoncom, etc)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Extra credit for doing it a particular way? What is this, some kind of homework problem?

Comment: No, I would just prefer not having to install many other modules, for ease of installing my script, if I end up needing to install it on another Windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

File type information is found in the [registry](http://www.awitness.org/delphi_pascal_tutorial/source4/registry_associated_applications.html). You could look up the file extension's type with the [windows registry](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) module.

**Edit**: It appears icons are available through shell32, as seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=29137). The Python equivalent seems to be `ctypes.windll.shell32.ExtractIconA`, though I'm not sure about the syntax.

Comment: Broken link - please fix and edit and let me know to remove my downvote. More info on python syntax will be appreciated ;)