# How can I extract the associated icon from any file using Python? I can do it in PowerShell, there must be a way to do it in Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, win32gui

On Windows, is there a Python equivalent to the PowerShell code below? What it does is it outputs the icon of any file that's given to it, the associated file.

I can get the icon of an executable using `win32gui.ExtractIconEx()`. I tried changing it to `win32gui.ExtractAssociatedIcon()` to mimic PowerShell but that didn't work.

This is the PowerShell code that extracts the icon of the (any) associated file:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing;
[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($filePath).ToBitmap().Save("$outputIconPath)
```

Does anyone know the equivalent to this in Python?

Comment: The method you're using in the PowerShell code is from a .Net class. Win32 API and .Net API are fundamentally different things. You're probably looking for the [pythonnet package](https://pythonnet.github.io/).

Comment: `[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon()` is a managed wrapper around `shell32.dll!ExtractIcon*`. You can call it [via `ctypes.windll` in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990092/how-to-find-via-python-the-icon-associated-with-a-windows-file)